# Should I allocate a Vec with bumpalo?

Tags: memory, memory-management, rust

I need arrays allocated dynamically so I need a memory pool for doing this efficiently. I found https://github.com/fitzgen/bumpalo but it looks like it does not support allocating direct arrays. Should I allocate a vector like this:

```
use bumpalo::{Bump, collections::Vec};
let bump = Bump::new();
let mut v = Vec::new_in(&bump);
```

and get its slice every time I need it?

Problem is that I can't force the vector to have the exact size I want. My arrays always have a fixed size (size determined at runtime though). I think Vec is for things that grow in size.

Comment: If your array always has a fixed size, couldn't you use arrays instead of vectors - e.g. `let v = bump.alloc([ElemType::default(); SIZE])`

Comment: @user4815162342 I meant that it's constant meaning that I don't need to resize it after it's done, but the size is determined at runtime so doing this is not possible

Comment: You can always wrap the `Vec` in a custom struct that doesn't allow the size to change.

Comment: @Lagerbaer yes but this is not the point. I want to use a memory pool for these allocations so it recycles stuff

Comment: I have hit this problem as well, and didn't find much support. Custom/smarter allocation strategies is a weak spot in Rust right now. (For a related problem of needing to allocate dynamically-sized types in an arena, I ended up writing my own allocator.) As an approximation you can use `Box<[T]>`/`into_boxed_slice` and that might work well enough - but to really get what you want I suspect you'll have to roll your own, for now.

Comment: It is certainly idiomatic to use `Vec` for non-resizing stuff, but if, for example you want to save the extra `usize` of capacity, you can use `Box<[T]>`.

Comment: Hmm, looking like bumpalo has a bunch of `alloc_slice_X()` methods. Check them out

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this requires me to have the slice beforehand, which I do not and cannot as it would take too much time to allocate and thus I'd not need bumpalo at all

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Not all of the methods: there are `alloc_slice_fill_default()`, `alloc_slice_fill_iter()` and `alloc_slice_fill_with()`. And if you can't even have a default value, you can always use `bump.alloc_slice_fill_with(len, |_| MaybeUninit::uninit())` and then initialize the values and `unsafe { &mut *(slice as *mut _ as *mut [T]) }` or `MaybeUninit::slice_assume_init_mut()` if you use nightly.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman but it returns a slice to the data. I wanted to own the data and get the slice when needed. Otherwise is pretty useless

Comment: If you need, for some reason, to be the owner (`T` and not `&mut T`), you don't have a solution simply because in Rust you can only move sized types and slice is unsized.

Comment: Wait a minute... *"I want to use a memory pool for these allocations so it recycles stuff"* - `bumpalo::Bump` is titularly a [bump allocator](https://os.phil-opp.com/allocator-designs/#bump-allocator) which by-design cannot reuse deallocated memory. *"The disadvantage of bump allocation is that there is no general way to deallocate individual objects or reclaim the memory region for a no-longer-in-use object."* - [bumpalo readme](https://github.com/fitzgen/bumpalo). It seems a poor fit for a recycling memory pool, at least not without a lot of work and planning.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to own the data and get the slice when needed.

`bumpalo` currently only provides growable collections, but it should be straightforward to write a non-growable one. For example:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use bumpalo::Bump;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BumpArray<'bump, T> {
    data: &'bump mut [T],
    _marker: PhantomData<T>, // we're dropping T values
}

impl<'bump, T> BumpArray<'bump, T> {
    // Just an example - you could also provide `new_with()` or similar
    // with different bounds on `T`.
    pub fn new_default(bump: &'bump Bump, size: usize) -> Self
    where
        T: Default,
    {
        BumpArray {
            data: bump.alloc_slice_fill_default(size),
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        self.data
    }

    pub fn as_slice_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        self.data
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for BumpArray<'_, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if std::mem::needs_drop::<T>() {
            for val in self.data.iter_mut() {
                unsafe {
                    std::ptr::drop_in_place(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The manual drop is required because bumpalo doesn't call `drop()`. In this case it allosw us to take advantage of ownership and execute the drops on individual elements (for types that require drops in the first place) much sooner than the whole arena is deallocated. It does require a bit of unsafe, but one that is fairly easy to reason about. Feel free to omit the `Drop` implementation and the `_marker` field if you use types that don't implement `Drop`.

Comment: why do I need to deallocate each individual element? This array is mostly for integer types, so I won't be deallocating each one. Is it possible to not deallocate each one so do not use unsafe?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs It's not necessary to execute the drops if you're storing copy types like numbers. That's what the last sentence refers to - feel free to omit the whole `Drop` implementation if you're storing non-`Drop` types in the array.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs On the other hand, if you're not dropping the elements, then there is very little difference between this "owned" type and the slice returned by `alloc_slice_fill_default()`.